# Socketio on https using redis

Tags: node.js, ssl, redis, socket.io, lets-encrypt

I have a webapplication on a bitnami lamp stack, the os is ubuntu and it uses Apache as a webserver.
The SSL Certificate is generated using Let's Encrypt. I can visit the site on http and https.

```
Furthermore I am using following stacks:
 - nodejs
 - socket.io
 - redis
```

Sending notifications on my local machine work fine, the websocket works.

But on my production Server which runs on https it does not work. I Keep getting following error messages:

> socket.io.js:2 GET https://mypage.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNxGNEt
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

This is how my `socket.js` (Server) Looks like:

```
var app   = require('http').createServer(handler);
var fs    = require('fs');
var io    = require('socket.io')(app);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

// class declaration
var Redis = require('ioredis');

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {});

var redisUserSignedUp = new Redis();

redisUserSignedUp.subscribe('signed-up-channel');

redisUserSignedUp.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

// run server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server runs!');
});
```

In my production I currently am trying it like this:

```
var app = require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/serverKey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/serverCrt.pem')
 }, handler);
var fs    = require('fs');
var io    = require('socket.io')(app);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

// class declaration
var Redis = require('ioredis');

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {});

var redisUserSignedUp = new Redis();

redisUserSignedUp.subscribe('signed-up-channel');

redisUserSignedUp.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

// run server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server runs!');
});
```

And I am trying to Access it like this:

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/serverKey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/serverCrt.pem'),
    requestCert: true    
}

var app   = require('https').createServer(options, handler);
```

local:

```
const socket = io('http://myapp.test:3000'); // localhost dev Folder is mapped to this .test url
socket.on('signed-in-channel:App\\Events\\UserSignedIn', (data) => {
   …
```

production:

```
var socket = io('mypage.com:3000', {secure: true});
```

Comment: Try to add https on your connection url
`var socket = io('https://mypage.com:3000', {secure: true});`

Comment: @domready already tested does not work

Comment: have you tried? `var socket = io('ws://mypage.com:3000', {secure: true})`

Answer (score 0):

You only create a http server but to connect with ssl you need a https server.

```js
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./file.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./file.crt')
};

var app = require('https').createServer(handler);
```

Comment: was a guess then on your `socket.js` you bound with the http. Can you update your example with the full https implementation?

Comment: ok I updated the Question with the https implementation on my production Server

Comment: Ok, looks fine for me. Do you get a 200 status when you try to call `https://mypage.com:3000`?

Comment: I cant Access the production Server like that a simple error Connection refused
`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
`

Comment: Did you install a firewall like `ufw` or something on you Ubuntu server?

Comment: I do not know I did not install something manually, how to check that

Comment: I'm only familiar with `ufw` you can test it with `sudo ufw status`. If you get any output you need to enable the 3000 port on ufw.

Comment: its Returns Status: inactive

Comment: I changed the port and now I get this error `net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID` any ideas?

Comment: Check your server and computer clock for correctness.

Comment: the utc time is correct if one compares it with my timezone

Comment: Sry but i’m not sure what a issue are behind that error message.